# Deployed Azure WebJob HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, ssh.net

I just deployed a webjob in our Azure App Service and when i tested it, it returned this error

> "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM
> component."

the application just retrieves a file from SFTP server then process the csv file using streamReader

```
Console.WriteLine("Reading lines from : " + file.FullName);
Console.WriteLine("SFTP Directory : " + client.WorkingDirectory);

var lines = new List<string>();
using (var stream = new StreamReader(client.OpenRead(file.FullName), ASCIIEncoding.ASCII))
{
    while (!stream.EndOfStream)
    {
        lines.Add(stream.ReadLine());
    }
    lineArray = lines.ToArray();
}
```

This works when I run it locally.  but when its deployed in Azure its not working. Not sure what I'm missing out.

Library  used for SSH: SSH.NET (Renci) 2020.0.2

UPDATE: (the full exception)

> [10/19/2022 08:38:40 > 18cb2c: ERR ] Unhandled Exception:
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has
> been returned from a call to a COM component. [10/19/2022 08:38:40 >
> 18cb2c: ERR ]    at
> System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IWebBrowser2.Navigate2(Object&
> URL, Object& flags, Object& targetFrameName, Object& postData, Object&
> headers) [10/19/2022 08:38:40 > 18cb2c: ERR ]    at
> System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.PerformNavigate2(Object& URL, Object&
> flags, Object& targetFrameName, Object& postData, Object& headers)
> [10/19/2022 08:38:40 > 18cb2c: ERR ]    at
> System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.set_Url(Uri value) [10/19/2022
> 08:38:40 > 18cb2c: ERR ]    at
> OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager.<>c__DisplayClass30_0.b__0()
> [10/19/2022 08:38:40 > 18cb2c: ERR ]    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
> preserveSyncCtx) [10/19/2022 08:38:40 > 18cb2c: ERR ]    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
> preserveSyncCtx) [10/19/2022 08:38:40 > 18cb2c: ERR ]    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) [10/19/2022
> 08:38:40 > 18cb2c: ERR ]    at
> System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() [10/19/2022 08:38:40 >
> 18cb2c: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed [10/19/2022 08:38:40 >
> 18cb2c: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code -532462766

Comment: .NET has no SFTP client. Using SFTP or SSH is a pain in .NET. Which library are you using? If that library is a wrapper over a COM component, you'll have to actually install that component on any machine you want to use it. You can't just copy the DLL. For that reason alone using COM in a cloud environment is a bad idea

Comment: Im using Renci.SshNet for the library.

Comment: Which version? And what's the *full* exception text? The full exception text contains the location of the error, any inner exceptions and a stack trace that shows the chain of calls that resulted in the exception. The stack trace will show which library and which method threw. You can easily get it with `Exception.ToString()`.

Comment: updated my question to add in details. Thanks!

Comment: The error has nothing to do with SFTP. It was raised by the ancient WebBrowser control that requires Internet Explorer. That in turn is used by  `OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager` which was provided by an **obsolete** NuGet package [that was renamed to SharePointPnPCoreOnline](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/2003) in 2018 before it was eventually [abandoned in 2020](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharePointPnPCoreOnline/). You definitely don't need a WebBrowser to authenticate to Microsoft 365 from Azure

Comment: The `PnP` part refers to Patterns and Practices, a grou/documentation set/libraries that were created around 2005-2012 to make architecting .NET applications easier. It had **nothing** to do with SharePoint. SharePoint "borrowed" the term when some libraries and guidance were created to make building applications easier because the API and docs at the time was ... a mess. These libraries were built before SharePoint Online and certainly before Microsoft Graph and Azure AD. That's why `OfficeDevPnP` uses a WinForms control. It tried to show a SharePoint login web page and crashed

Comment: In short, whatever your WebJob does, it doesn't need `OfficeDevPnP` nor can it use it. You should check the [PnP Core SDK](https://github.com/pnp/pnpcore) which replaces previous SharePoint Online SDKs. You should also check whether you can just Microsoft Graph directly though. As the landing page explains `As Microsoft Graph is our recommended API to work with Microsoft 365, the SDK will favor Microsoft Graph whenever it makes sense, the "fall back" to SharePoint REST only happens when Microsoft Graph can't provide the needed data or consistency.`

Comment: oh i would need to push the data from the sftp to sharepoint but thanks! i will check the package and use the recommended api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Panagiotis, I found the issue! I was using the authentication manager of OfficeDevPnP.

```
OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager authManager = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager();
```

I removed it and it worked already.